# Is there UI inspector tool similar to hawkeye that works with .net 4.5?

Tags: c#, winforms, element, inspect

I'm working with a winforms application that is targeting .net 4.5 and I really need to inspect the UI elements.  I've used [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect wpf elements in the past, and I've come across [Hawekeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/) as well.  However, it appears hawkeye is not compatible with .net 4.5.  Are there any tools out there than can give me similar results?

Comment: Out of curiosity, As you already know, *HawkEye* is an open source, Have you tried to compile it to 4.5 by yourself ?

Comment: I did.  Had to change some project dependencies to pick up the N4 libraries.  Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like the old tools no longer work like UI Spy either. Microsoft have an Inspect tool available here ([Inspect tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521.aspx)). It's part of the Win8 SDK.

I'm looking at the same problem myself today, so will be trying it shortly.

Comment: I installed the win8 SDK already, and didn't have any luck tracking down the inspect tool.  Their line "It is located in the \bin\<platform> folder of the SDK installation path (Inspect.exe)." wasn't all that helpful, and a system search didn't turn anything up. I'm curious to see what your results are.

Comment: I found it here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86

Comment: Excellent, there it is.  I focused all my time looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows.  I'm not too fond of the interface compared to snoop, but it may be the only game in town for what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Inspect can also view the attributes, can't change them like hawkeye.

Answer (score 3):

There is Hawkeye 2 (https://github.com/odalet/Hawkeye2). It works for me with .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

Try the nuget package: [WinForm.Inspector.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinForm.Inspector.Tool/#)

**Setup documentation**

- Instantiate the Inspector in your project.

  `Inspector inspector = new Inspector();`
- Ignore specific controls ex. buttons.

  `inspector.IgnoreTypes = new Type[] { typeof(Button) };`
- Skip controls ex. invisible and disabled.

  `inspector.SkipChilds = GetChildAtPointSkip.Invisible | GetChildAtPointSkip.Disabled;`

Run your project and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to open the ControlViewer.

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and move your mouse over the controllers to select them.

[image]

Comment: From testing this out, it only seems to work for WinForm windows within the same application. Not the same as Snoop/Hawkeye which can allow you to inspect any application window.

Answer (score 1):

There is `Spy++.exe` within Microsoft Visual Studio, very useful and works like that.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2019, you might find it here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe