# How to capture the name of the element under mouse click in any WPF 3rd party application?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, plugins, wpf-controls

I am trying to design a plugin to a 3rd party application in which I am supposed to capture the name of the element( or any property of the element like tool tip etc.) which the user clicks. The thing is the application is not written by me and I don't have any access to it's code. Is there any way in C# for this ?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343614/is-there-ui-inspector-tool-similar-to-hawkeye-that-works-with-net-4-5  Both Snool and Hawkeye (which are mentioned in the comments and already do what you're trying to do) are open source, so you may be able to integrate those in your project, or at least see how they do things.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But, I am not supposed to use any 3rd party tools in my project.